# How to fetch documents from Firestore that has matching at least few items in array?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am making social media app using SwiftUI and Firebase. I am trying to fetch users that has at least 3 interests in common, but I don't want to fetch all users and then filter out because it would be too heavy for bigger amount of users. Right now I have something like this:

```
func fetchAllUsers() {
        guard let uid = UserViewModel.shared.currentSession?.uid else { return }
        let ref = db
            .collection(Constants.Firebase.usersDB)
        ref.getDocuments { snapshot, error in
            if let error = error {
                self.errorService = .error(message: error.localizedDescription)
            }else if let snapshot = snapshot {
                do {
                    let allUsers = try snapshot.documents.compactMap({ try $0.data(as: User.self)})
                    self.allUser = allUsers.filter({$0.id != uid})
                } catch let error {
                    self.errorService = .error(message: error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Each user has value of type `interests` which is an array of strings, I want to fetch only these users who has matching interests (at least 3).

Comment: There's nothing in that code that does any kind of matching; where is the code you've written that attempts that task? This sounds like a job for `array-contains-any`, which is a logical `OR` but it has a limit to 10 clauses so if there are more than 10 interests that won't work directly. You may also have two run three queries to narrow the dataset. But without a clear question and seeing the code you've attempted, that's just guesswork. Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't understand what isn't clear in this question, my code shows basic fetch function that fetches all users from firestore, what I ask is how to limit number of users to only these who has in their interests array at least 3 matching string to interests of the current user.

Comment: I understand. This site is not a code-writing service; we can help with a problem in existing code that you're stuck on, not write the code for you. Ideally, the question would contain the code showing an attempt to query the data. It's important because we don't know for example, how many interests there are. Is it a pre-set list less than 10 or an infinite number? What's the structure? e.g. does it lend itself to actually doing the needed query(s)? Is there a collection "interests" with all of the user uid's stored that have that interest?  What if all uses have three interests in common?

Comment: Also, per your above comment - *3 matching string to interests of the current user* - which is different than what's in the question - *I am trying to fetch users that has at least 3 interests in common* -. Fetching users that have three interests in common with the current user is quite different than fetching *users* that have three interests in common, right? So we need a little clarity there - is it matching *this* user or *all users* that have three interests in common. Just update and clarify the question a bit and we'll take a look!